# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: execute is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I made a discord bot that i want to check a minecraft server but the embed has this issue: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: execute is not defined

my code:

```
module.exports = {
name: 'mcserver',
description: 'get information about a minecraft server',
execute(client, message, args, Discord){

    const util = require('minecraft-server-util');

    util.status('mc.procrafting.net', {port: 25789, enableSRV: true, timeout: 5000, protocalVersion: 47}).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        execute(client, message, args);{
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed(data)
        .setColor('#BFCDEB')
        .setTitle('Mc server status')
        .addFields(
            {name: 'Server IP', value: response.host},
            {name: 'Online Players', value: response.onlinePlayers},
            {name: 'Max Players', value: response.maxPlayers},
            {name: 'Version', value: response.version}
        )
        .setFooter('mc by Procrafting');

        message.channel.send(embed)
    }})
    .catch((error) => {
    throw error;
    })
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show the code of when you call the command

Comment: Is this what you wanted?     } else if (command == 'checkserver'){
        client.commands.get('mcserver').execute(message, args);
    }

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I think that you wanted to write

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    execute = () => {
        ...
    }
}
```

However, I can't find how this execute is supose to work, can you please share the documents that you're using?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I not longer get the error but the bot doesnt send a embed of the message than I want.

Comment: @The Zeitgeist, the syntax in OP's code should work perfectly fine when called correctly.

Comment: @user15517071, shouldn't it be `execute: (client, message, args, Discord) => {...}`?

Comment: @Louiscooldude41, you can try wrapping the embed in an object and use it as the 2nd argument to `message.channel.send()`, i.e. `message.channel.send({ embed: embed });`.

Comment: @Logan Devine, there are multiple ways to do this. OP's way and your way would both work, but The Zeitgeist's will not work at all.

Comment: @user15517071 -- sorry: I mistook Zeitgeist as being OP.

Comment: The export is an object, the syntax `= () => {}` is invalid object syntax

Comment: I have tried doing the suggestions but in discord the bot still doesn't respond

Comment: You mentioned that you no longer get the error, does the execute function run now? Try logging inside the function. If you now have a new issue consider posting a new question.

Comment: I no longer encounter the error, I just don't get the embed that I need

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling the command correctly. It expects `client, message, args, Discord`, but you provide `message, args`.

Change the way you call the command to include all the arguments needed.